# Relationship hasOne, hasMany Eloquent with MongoDB return empty array

Tags: laravel, mongodb, relationship, lumen

I'm trying to make a hasOne / hasMany relationship in Lumen using [jenssegers/mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) library, but It doesn't work for me, I did try this options:

- `return $this->hasMany(Token::class,'_id.toString()','token.toString()');`
- `return $this->hasMany(Token::class,'_id','token');`
- When I Used raw query work in method It work for me
- When I made the data insert I saved the foreign field as `new ObtjectID`

This is the user model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID;

class Usuario extends Model
{   
    //Tabla seleccionada
    protected $table = 'usuario';

    //Campos de la tabla
    protected $fillable = [
        '_id',         
        'usuario',
        'token',
    ];

    //Llave primaria
    protected $primaryKey = '_id';
   
    //Relaciones
    public function token()
    {            
        return $this->hasMany(Token::class, 'usuario','_id');
    } 
}
```

This is the token model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Token extends Model 
{   
    //Tabla seleccionada
    protected $table = 'token';

    //Campos de la tabla
    protected $fillable = [
        '_id',  
        'nombre',  
        'usuario',
        'token',  
        'fecha',      
    ];

    //Llave primaria
    protected $primaryKey = '_id';

    //Relaciones
    public function usuario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Usuario::class,"_id","usuario");
    }

}
```

And this is the method:

```
      $result =  Usuario::with('token')->where('eliminado', 0)->get(); 
      if ($result->count() > 0) {
          return response() -> json(
              array('data' => $result, 'message' => config('constants.messages.3.message')),
              config('constants.messages.3.code')
          );

      }else{
          return response() -> json(
              array('data' => $result, 'message' => config('constants.messages.4.message')),
              config('constants.messages.4.code')
          );
      }
```

Thanks for reading me

Comment: _"Doesn't work for me"_ does not really tell us anything, what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi Remul, It return empty array

Comment: please share your code, models, controllers

Comment: Hi @OMR I updated the ask right now

Answer (score 0):

you should adjust your relation like in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

in Usuario Model:

```
  public function tokens() 
 // it's convention to use 's' because of this relation returns collection not 
//single model instance ....
    {            
        return $this->hasMany(Token::class, 'usuario');
    }
```

in Token Model:

```
public function usuario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Usuario::class,"usuario");
    }
```

Comment: Hi @OMR, thanks for replying me, I did test your solution and the result is the same, a empty array :(